# Is there any stubbing possible on Robolectric Activity?

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, stubbing

I am testing a method within my code which calls Activity.requestPermissions(). I want to use Robolectric shadowing features so I create the Activity with Robolectric using

```
val mockActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(AppCompatActivity::class.java)
```

But I would like the shadowed activity to trigger a generic answer on the requestPermissions() call.

If it would be possible to use a Robolectric-shadowed `Activity` as a mock for Mockito I could do something like:

```
@Test
fun testRequestPermissions()
{
    val myCallback = MyCallback()

    val mockActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(AppCompatActivity::class.java)

    val shadowActivity = shadowOf(mockActivity)
    shadowActivity.grantPermissions(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)

    `when`(
        mockActivity.requestPermissions(
            eq(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)), anyInt())).then {
        myCallback.notify(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), intArrayOf(
            PERMISSION_GRANTED, PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        ...
    }
}

class MyCallback
{
    fun notify(arrayOf: Array<String>, intArrayOf: IntArray){...}

}
```

But it is not possible to stub methods with Mockito on a Robolectric `Activity`. Does Robolectric provide something like method stubbing?

Unfortunetly I cannot use any Custom Shadow here. I tried doing this:

```
@Implements(AppCompatActivity::class)
class ShadowAppCompatActivity() : ShadowActivity()
{
    @Implementation
    override fun requestPermissions(permissions: Array<out String>, requestCode: Int)
    {
        super.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)
        myCallback.notify(permissions, requestCode)
    }

}
```

But requestPermissions() is final in `ShadowActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(violationsActivity); 

ShadowApplication application = Shadows.shadowOf(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());

            String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            application.grantPermissions(permissions);  
     ShadowActivity.PermissionsRequest permissionRequest= shadowActivity.getLastRequestedPermission();
        assertEquals(1,permissionRequest.requestCode);
```

This code will helped me testing Activitiy.requestPermission(), you can use activity also instead of application